# Magento 2.3.5p2: Uncaught Error: Create invoice with shipment issue

Tags: magento2, invoice, shipment

I am getting this error on creating invoice with shipment from the admin:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUrl() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Did you change anything on this XML (vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_track.xml), tracking_url object is passed to the block using arguments in that XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_shipment = $block->getShipment() ?>
$_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order) : ?>
    <?php $trackCollection = $_order->getTracksCollection($_shipment->getId()) ?>
    <?php if ($trackCollection) : ?>
        <br />
        <table class="shipment-track">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shipped By')) ?></th>
                <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Tracking Number')) ?></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($trackCollection as $_item) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getTitle()) ?>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($this->helper('Magento\Shipping\Helper\Data')->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($_item)) ?>" target="_blank"> 
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?> 
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Created a template file in the custom theme: Magento_Sales/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml**